# Error on executing rga.open(instance="ga", where="~/ga.rga") from a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, google-analytics

I am trying to run a r script through a batch file so that I can schedule the R script to run at a regular basis. The R script retrieves data from Google Analytics and dumps the data into SQL Server database.

The R script runs perfectly fine under R Studio but when I try to execute the same R script through batch file, it fails giving this error -

"Error in body_config(body, multipart) : Object redirect.uri not found
Calls rga.open ... modify_config -> setdiff -> as.vector -> body_config
Execution halted"

My batch file looks like this:
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\sc\Documents\R Sources\SocialMedia\ExtractBlogStats.r"
pause

My Rscript looks like:

```
library(devtools)

#install_github("rga", "skardhamar")
library(rga)

#install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)

myconn <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=SocialMedia;trusted_connection=true')


options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

#rga.open(instance="ga")


rga.open(instance="ga", where="~/ga.rga")


id <- "XXXXXXXX" # Valid ID in actual script file

end <- Sys.Date() - 1
start <- end - 1

by.practice <- ga$getData(id, start.date = start, end.date= end, 
                        metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:totalEvents",
                        dimensions = "ga:eventAction",
                        sort = "",
                        filters = "",
                        segment = "",
                        start = 1,
                        max = 1000)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but are you working behind a proxy? That may explain why it works in RStudio and not called as batch script.

Comment: Are you running the batch file on the same machine where you run RStudio? And as the same user? The "~" in the path is for a user specific home, if the batch script is run by a scheduler, then a different user home may be used for "~". Perhaps try setting a full path there?

Comment: @MrFlick - Yes, I am running the batch file on the same machine where I run RStudio and as the same user. Both the paths in my batch file are full paths. Are you suggesting something else?

Comment: @user3749083 It just looked like `where="~/ga.rga"` could be troublesome because of that tilde and in one place it was using a cached authentication and in another it was not. Just to check you can print out `path.expand("~/ga.rga")` to see where it's resolving to. You might also want to add a `traceback()` if you still get the error right after the `rga.open` to get an idea of what it's trying to do at that point.

Comment: @MrFlick - I included path.expand and noticed that there was a difference in the value when I run inside RStudio ("C:/Users/sc/Documents/ga.rga") Vs batch file ("C:\\Users\\sc\\Documents/ga.rga"). I read on where clause and found out that "If you want to store the instance locally, this can be done by adding the where attribute:". So I modified my code to specify the explicit path instead of tilde [where ="C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia/ga.rga"] but it does not help. Also, I added setwd("C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia") but that doesn't help either.

Comment: @MrFlick - Also, I have never used traceback earlier. I added it to the Rscript where I call my function `source("C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia/ExtractBlogPracticeStats.R")
extract.blog.stats.by.practice()
traceback()` but it doesn't return any extra information. When I try testing traceback() inside RStudio it says "No traceback() available"

Comment: @user3749083 The traceback should be called immediately after an error (and is generally only available after an error has occurred). If you're sourcing it, you may have to `print(traceback())`. Using `where=file.path("~","ga.rga")` should help build a consistent path but it doesn't look like that's the problem exactly. But the current error message just doesn't give enough info for me to figure out what's going on. Sorry.

Comment: @MrFlick - Nevermind,  I restarted my R session and cleared my environment and now I get a different error in R Studio on rga.open(instance="ga"). Thanks for all your help. I need to get a better handle on Google Analytics authentication and token expiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the entire solution -

Step 1 -- Create Initial Authentication Objects

```
#Initial Objects
# dev tools is needed because we need to use it's function install_github

# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

# install_github("rga", "skardhamar")
library(rga)

library(RODBC)

config.folder.location <- "C:\\Users\\sc\\Documents\\R Sources\\SocialMedia\\Config"

working.directory <- config.folder.location

rga.open(instance="ga")

save(ga, file="C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia/config/ga.rga")


connection.string <- 'driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=SocialMedia;trusted_connection=true'

save(connection.string,  file = paste0(config.folder.location,'\\connection.string '))


# Google Analytics ID for ur site
google.analytics.id <- "XXXXXX"

save(google.analytics.id, file="google.analytics.id")
```

Step 2 -- Query Google Analaytics

```
# dev tools is needed because we need to use it's function install_github
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

# install_github("rga", "skardhamar")
library(rga)

# install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)


#*********************************************************************************************************************
# Read arguments and store them in variables -- START
#*********************************************************************************************************************
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# First argument is read as working directory (location where config folder resides)
working.directory <- as.character(args[1])

if (length(args) >= 2){
  # Second argument is used as start date in GA Query
  start <- as.Date(args[2])
}else{
 start <- Sys.Date() - 1
}

if (length(args) == 3){
# Third argument is used as end date in GA Query  
 end <- as.Date(args[3]) 
}else{
 end <- start
}

#*********************************************************************************************************************
# Read arguments and store them in variables -- END
#*********************************************************************************************************************

#*********************************************************************************************************************
# Use arguments values to setup the environment and load initial objects -- START
#*********************************************************************************************************************

# Set working directory to the passed value
setwd(working.directory)

# load Google Analytics ID from Config folder
load("google.analytics.id")

# Load SQL Connection String
load("connection.string")

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

# load pre-authentcated Google Analytics object "ga"
load("ga.rga")

# Check if the ga token has expired. If it has then refersh token.
if (ga$isTokenExpired()){
  ga$refreshToken()
}

#*********************************************************************************************************************
# Use arguments values to setup the environment and load initial objects -- END
#*********************************************************************************************************************

# Runs Google Analytics query for the provided id and limits data by date (i.e., start.date = date and end.date = date)
# Wrapped in try/catch to handle scenarios when GA does not return any rows



blog.stats = tryCatch({
 ga$getData(google.analytics.id, 
            start.date = start, 
            end.date = end, 
            metrics = "ga:sessions, ga:users, ga:newUsers, ga:sessionDuration, ga:timeOnPage, ga:pageviews",
            dimensions = "ga:date, ga:pageTitle, ga:medium, ga:hasSocialSourceReferral, ga:source, ga:referralPath",
            sort = "",
            filters = "",
            segment = "",
            start = 1,
            max = 10000)           
 }, warning = function(w) { 
    # print("warning")
    return(NULL)
 }, error = function(e) {
    # print("error")
    return(NULL)
 }, finally = {  
    # print("inside Finally")
}
)

if(length(blog.stats)>0 ){
# Convert Numeric To Integer
  blog.stats[,"sessions"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"sessions"])
  blog.stats[,"users"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"users"])
  blog.stats[,"newUsers"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"newUsers"])
  blog.stats[,"sessionDuration"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"sessionDuration"])
  blog.stats[,"timeOnPage"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"timeOnPage"])
  blog.stats[,"pageviews"] <- as.integer(blog.stats[,"pageviews"])


# Assign columnnames that match the table's column name in the database
colnames(blog.stats) <- c("Date", "PageTitle", "Medium", "HasSocialSourceReferral", "TrafficSource", "ReferralPath", "Sessions", "Users", "NewUsers", "SessionDurationSeconds", "TimeOnPageSeconds", "PageViews" )

# Open a Connection
myconn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection.string)

# Prepare Delete Query
delete.query <- paste0("DELETE  FROM  GoogleAnalyticsBlogStats WHERE Date >='",start,"' AND Date <='",end,"'")

# Execute Delete Query
sqlQuery(myconn,delete.query,  errors= FALSE)


# Insert rows in the table
sqlSave(myconn, blog.stats, "GoogleAnalyticsBlogStats", safer = FALSE, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)

# Close the connection to the database
odbcClose(myconn)
}
```

Step 3 --- Execute the Rscript from the batch file

Batch file looks like this -

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe" "D:\Social Media Analytics\R Scripts\ExtractGoogleAnalyticsBlogStats.r" "D:\\Social Media Analytics\\R Scripts\\Config"
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
a) Executed rga.open(instance="ga") inside RStudio

b) Which led me to a URL and generate a code

c) Pasted the code in RStudio console

d) Saved ga object on local file system -- save(ga, file="C:/Users/sc/Documents/R 
Sources/SocialMedia/ga.rga")

e) Removed the rga.open call from the function - extract.blog.stats.by.practice()

```
extract.blog.stats.by.practice = function(id = "XXXXXXX") {
library(devtools)
library(rga)
library(RODBC)
myconn <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=SocialMediaSink;trusted_connection=true')

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

#rga.open(instance="ga")
setwd("C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia")

end <- Sys.Date() - 1
start <- end - 1

by.practice <- NULL

by.practice <- ga$getData(id, start.date = start, end.date= end, 
                        metrics = "ga:sessions,ga:totalEvents",
                        dimensions = "ga:eventAction",
                        sort = "",
                        filters = "",
                        segment = "",
                        start = 1,
                        max = 1000)


# Convert Numeric To Integer
practice <- by.practice[,1]
sessions <- as.integer(by.practice[,2])
totalEvents <- as.integer(by.practice[,3])

# Create a dataframe that mimics the structure of the database table - BlogPracticeStats
practice.stats <- data.frame(practice, end, sessions, totalEvents, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Assign columnnames that match the table's column name in the database
colnames(practice.stats) <- c("Practice", "Date", "Sessions", "TotalEvents")

# Insert rows in the table
sqlSave(myconn, practice.stats, "BlogPracticeStats", safer = FALSE, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
odbcClose(myconn)

 }
```

f) Included a load of "ga" from locally saved copy in RunFunction.r

```
source("C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia/ExtractBlogPracticeStats.R")
load("C:/Users/sc/Documents/R Sources/SocialMedia/ga.rga")
extract.blog.stats.by.practice()
```

g) Executed Batch File

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\sc\Documents\R Sources\SocialMedia\RunFunction.r"
pause
```